# Why a breakpoint works in x64dbg but not in IDA?

Tags: ida, debugging, x64dbg

I've spent all morning trying to find a solution to debug with IDA the same function I'm debugging in x64dbg.

In x64dbg, I just go to Symbols -> ws2_32.dll -> WSARecvFrom -> F2 (set breakpoint):

[image]

Then I get the RVA of the call to WSARecvFrom (tracing returns until reaching the caller):

[image]

Go to IDA -> press G -> input the RVA -> OK:

[image]

I put a breakpoint with F2 in the IDA View-A and even in the Pseudocode-A:

[image]

I run the program in x64dbg I hit the breakpoint but in IDA it doesn't hit any breakpoint

I've tried with both "Local Windows debugger" and with "Windbg(x64) debugger" in IDA options but none of them made any difference

How can I set a breakpoint similar to x64dbg so I can debug the runtime with IDA?